# Take text from searchBar and make it useable in URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an app to view anime from myanimelist.net. I have written the code to parse the text through and display data, but so far it only displays data from a specific URL such as

```
https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=sword+art+online
```

I am trying to get the searchBar text to passthrough into where I have the link so it searches dynamically instead of only one anime at a time, like

```
https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=(search term here)
```

This is the code where the URL is

```
private func fetchData()
    {
        let feedParser = FeedParser()
        feedParser.parseFeed(url: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=")
            {
            (animeItems) in
                self.animeItems = animeItems
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation
                    {
                    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .left)
                    }
            }
    }
```

This is the code I have to search a URL in my TableViewController.

Here is the bit from XMLparser.swift that handles HTTP auth

```
   func parseFeed(url: String, completionHandler: (([AnimeItem]) -> Void)?)
    {
        self.parserCompletionHandler = completionHandler


        //task.resume()
        let username = "MALPocket"
        let password = "qpwoeiruty"
        let logindata = String(format : "%@:%@", username, password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64String = logindata.base64EncodedString()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64String)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else
            {
                if let error = error
                {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

                return
            }
            print(data)

            /// parse the xml data
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }



        task.resume()
    }
```

I have tried doing things such as

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
    {
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
    {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and trying to save searchText to variables to add onto the link like

```
feedParser.parseFeed(url: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=\(searchText)")
```

but everything I have tried ends in unresolved identifier errors or worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, here is the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self

    fetchData(searchTerm: nil)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    print("search Text: \(searchText)")
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    self.fetchData(searchTerm: searchBar.text)
}


func fetchData(searchTerm: String?)
{
    var components = URLComponents(string: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml")

    if let searchTerm = searchTerm {
        components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: searchTerm)]
    }

    guard let urlString = components?.url?.absoluteString else { return }
    feedParser.parseFeed(url: urlString){ (animeItems) in
            self.animeItems = animeItems
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation
                {
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .left)
                }
        }
}
```

After this the search worked, it wouldn't do a second search properly as the array didn't reset so I also added in this to my parser code to delete the array and start again, now the search works.

```
animeItems.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what the error is, but likely you'll need to encode the search term so that it can be used with a query in a URL. Luckily Swift has support for this built in:

```
let encodedSearchTerm = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
feedParser.parseFeed(url: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=\(encodedSearchTerm)") { animeItems in
// Do something with your animeItems
}
```

Here's an example of how this could be used in a view controller. I don't know what your set up is like so this might be different, so this is just an example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    private let feedParser = FeedParser()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let searchText = searchBar.text ?? ""
        let encodedSearchTerm = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
        feedParser.parseFeed(url: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=\(encodedSearchTerm)") { animeItems in
            // Do something with your animeItems
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is to replace the original feedParser.parseFeed(url: "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=")?
I tried doing so and I got two errors, 
1 - Use of unresolved identifier 'searchText'
2 Braces here form a trailing closure separated from its callee by multiple newlines

Comment: I just coped your last line. You'll need to place this somewhere where you can get the search text, either in the callback for `textDidChange` or by getting `searchBar.text` somewhere else. I've updated the answer to have the closure

Comment: I've tried moving `let encodedSearchTerm = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""` in with `func searchBar` and `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked` but I can't get encodedSearchTerm to work, I just get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'encodedSearchTerm'` unless I am trying to put it in the wrong places

Comment: You need to keep all my code together, because the second line uses `encodedSearchTerm` which is defined on the first line. If you move them separately you'll get an error because it can't access the `encodedSearchTerm` from somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I've added a more complete answer. Please look at the code carefully to try and understand what's happening because I can't help much more than that without seeing how you've set everything up.

Comment: I don't know if it's acceptable to share files or not, but here is my xcode project in .zip [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UoC2ZzVxiB8Fhb7N8hNvsv9-jMejzuzT/view?usp=sharing)

It's rather messy and you can see lots of commented out code where I have attempted things that ultimately didn't work.

Comment: [Updated Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UoC2ZzVxiB8Fhb7N8hNvsv9-jMejzuzT/view?usp=sharing)